# PySpark trying to apply previous field's schema to next field

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Having this weird issue with PySpark. It seems to be trying to apply the schema for the previous field, to the next field, as it's processing.

Simplest test case I could come up with:

```python
%pyspark
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    DateType,
    StructType,
    StructField,
    StringType,
)

from datetime import date
from pyspark.sql import Row


schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("date", DateType(), True),
        StructField("country", StringType(), True),
    ]
)

test = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        Row(
            date=date(2019, 1, 1),
            country="RU",
        ),
    ],
    schema
)
```

Stacktrace:

```python
Fail to execute line 26:     schema
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-8579306903394369208.py", line 380, in <module>
    exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
  File "<stdin>", line 26, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 691, in createDataFrame
    rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 423, in _createFromLocal
    data = [schema.toInternal(row) for row in data]
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 601, in toInternal
    for f, v, c in zip(self.fields, obj, self._needConversion))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 601, in <genexpr>
    for f, v, c in zip(self.fields, obj, self._needConversion))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 439, in toInternal
    return self.dataType.toInternal(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 175, in toInternal
    return d.toordinal() - self.EPOCH_ORDINAL
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'toordinal'
```

Bonus information from running it locally rather than in Zepplin:

```python
self = DateType, d = 'RU'

    def toInternal(self, d):
        if d is not None:
>           return d.toordinal() - self.EPOCH_ORDINAL
E           AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'toordinal'
```

e.g., it's trying to apply `DateType` to `country`. If I get rid of `date`, it's fine. If I get rid of `country`, it's fine. Both together, is a no go.

Any ideas? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use a list of `Row`s, you don't need to specify the schema as well. This is because the `Row` already knows the schema.

The problem is happening because the [`pyspark.sql.Row`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Row) object does not maintain the order that you specified for the fields.

```python
print(Row(date=date(2019, 1, 1), country="RU"))
#Row(country='RU', date=datetime.date(2019, 1, 1))
```

From the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Row):

> Row can be used to create a row object by using named arguments, the fields will be sorted by names.

As you can see, the `country` field is being put first. When spark tries to create the DataFrame with the specified `schema`, it expects the first item to be a `DateType`.

One way to fix this is to put the fields in your `schema` in alphabetical order:

```python
schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("country", StringType(), True),
        StructField("date", DateType(), True)
    ]
)

test = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        Row(date=date(2019, 1, 1), country="RU")
    ],
    schema
)
test.show()
#+-------+----------+
#|country|      date|
#+-------+----------+
#|     RU|2019-01-01|
#+-------+----------+
```

Or in this case, there's no need to even pass in the `schema` to `createDataFrame`. It will be inferred from the `Row`s:

```python
test = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        Row(date=date(2019, 1, 1), country="RU")
    ]
)
```

And if you wanted to reorder the columns, use `select`:

```python
test = test.select("date", "country")
test.show()
#+----------+-------+
#|      date|country|
#+----------+-------+
#|2019-01-01|     RU|
#+----------+-------+
```

Comment: Wow, oops. If I had RTFM'd earlier I would have noticed that it says exactly `the fields will be sorted by names`! In this case, I think I do need the schema as I intend to load in some JSON data with e.g., nulls --- the `Row`s were just for testing (but evidently caused a problem I wouldn't have experienced otherwise). Thanks!